# List items in 2 columns with straight border

Tags: html, css

I have a list item. What I'm trying to achieve is when in mobile view, I want the list to show 2 items in a row.

So, I set the UL tag to `columns: 2`. It works perfectly, but the downside is since those items have border-top property, they will be a line gap on the middle.

May I know is there a way for me to make the border in full width without a gap and without changing to another html tag (since this list format is generated from WordPress widget)

Here an example of the problem.

```css
ul {
  display: block;
  columns: 2;
}

li {
  border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>TEST 1</li>
<li>TEST 2</li>
<li>TEST 3</li>
<li>TEST 4</li>
<li>TEST 5</li>
<li>TEST 6</li>
<li>TEST 7</li>
<li>TEST 8</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `column-gap: 0;` to your `ul`

```css
ul {
  display: block;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-columns: 2;
  /* Firefox */
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-gap: 0;
  /* Firefox */
  column-gap: 0;
}

li {
  border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>TEST 1</li>
  <li>TEST 2</li>
  <li>TEST 3</li>
  <li>TEST 4</li>
  <li>TEST 5</li>
  <li>TEST 6</li>
  <li>TEST 7</li>
  <li>TEST 8</li>
</ul>
```

> **Always use Webkit prefixs with the new CSS styles for better support**

Hope this was helpfull.

Comment: @nazrinnoorzan  please change the value in `-webkit-column-gap` I have updated the code please check it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use     `font-size: 0;` to `ul` and     `font-size: 15px;` to `li`

```css
ul {
  display: block;
  columns: 2;
  font-size: 0;
}

li {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>TEST 1</li>
<li>TEST 2</li>
<li>TEST 3</li>
<li>TEST 4</li>
<li>TEST 5</li>
<li>TEST 6</li>
<li>TEST 7</li>
<li>TEST 8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: tell me for more help!

Comment: This one not working for me though when I test at live site. Plus, what is the logic of setting the font differently for UL and LI ?

Comment: it is a trick to remove gap (also in `inline-block` spaces) and see in your F12 browser maybe it overrides by other

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `column-gap: 0;`. If I understood you correctly, this is what you need.

```css
ul {
  display: block;
  columns: 2;
  column-gap: 0;
}

li {
  border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>TEST 1</li>
<li>TEST 2</li>
<li>TEST 3</li>
<li>TEST 4</li>
<li>TEST 5</li>
<li>TEST 6</li>
<li>TEST 7</li>
<li>TEST 8</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You Can Try Another Way to use flex box**

```css
ul {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li {
  width:50%;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>TEST 1</li>
<li>TEST 2</li>
<li>TEST 3</li>
<li>TEST 4</li>
<li>TEST 5</li>
<li>TEST 6</li>
<li>TEST 7</li>
<li>TEST 8</li>
</ul>
```